# How to determine the convergence of the following series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Good evening to everyone!
I have the following series $$ \sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\left(-1\right)^{n }\left|\alpha -1\right|^n\frac{n!}{\left(n+1\right)!-n!+1} $$. I don't know from where to start to determine its convergence. Thanks for any possible response!

Comment: Because of the $\;(-1^\alpha)\;$ factor, are we to assume $\;\alpha\in\Bbb Z\;$ ?

Comment: @Joanpemo No, α∈R

Comment: Ratio Test, for example, will deal with $|\alpha-1|\ne 1$. For $\alpha=0$ and $\alpha=2$, use the alternating series (Leibniz) test. (I assume $(-1)^\alpha$ is a typo for $(-1)^n$.)

Comment: @AndreNicolas thanks I think I got what you meant. And yes the $/alpha$ was a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly ratio test:

$$\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=\frac{|\alpha-1|(n+1)!}{(n+2)!-(n+1)!+1}\frac{(n+1)!-n!+1}{n!}=$$

$$=|\alpha-1|\frac{\left(n\cdot n!+1\right)(n+1)}{(n+1)(n+1)!+1}=|\alpha-1|\frac{n+\frac1{n!}}{(n+1)+\frac1{n!}}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}|\alpha-1|$$

and the series converges exactly when $\;|\alpha-1|<1\;$

Comment: For $\alpha  > 2$ and $ \alpha  < 0 $ it's not convergent all that remained are $ \alpha  = 2$ and $\alpha  = 0$. How do I compute these?

Comment: @T4yl0r Isn't this written above? Perhaps I'm missing something, but the above says, unless I made some mistake, that the series converges iff $$|\alpha-1|<1\iff -1<\alpha-1<1\iff 0<\alpha<2$$

Comment: Oh! You're right!:)

Comment: @T4yl0r: For $\alpha$ equal to $0$ or $2$ we have convergence by the alternating series test, for note that $\frac{n!}{nn!+1}$ is decreasing with limit $0$.

Comment: @T4yl0r Note the above comment by André, as it is important (and true). I solved your question when you still had $\;(-1)^\alpha)\;$, but I see you changed that later to $\;(-1)^n\;$ , so the convergence interval is in fact $\;\alpha\in[0,2]\;$ .

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. One may write, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
\frac{n!}{\left(n+1\right)!-n!+1} =\frac1{n+1/n!} \sim \frac1n
$$ and the initial series is convergent for $|\alpha-1|<1$.

When $|\alpha-1|=1$ we obtain a conditionally convergent series.

Comment: If  $\alpha$ is $2$ or $0$ the series still converges because  it is alternating, with terms going to $0.$

Comment: @user254665 Ok. My answer was given before the question was modified. I will edit my answer accordingly. Thanks

Comment: Happens a lot. Yesterday I saw a Q  drastically modified just after an A appeared.